# Gluon SceneBuilder NavigationDrawer feature seems to be broken?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, gluon-mobile

I'm currently working on a mobile app with gluonFx, and I'm looking to implement a navigation drawer in SceneBuilder. Every time I try, I get the result that is in the screenshot I've attached. Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

I can give any FXML or code needed, just let me know.[image]

Comment: Even if the `NavigationDrawer` is listed as a component you can drag and drop to a container, you are not supposed to do so: the drawer is a control that is displayed in a popup, not in your main container. Just follow the Gluon samples on how to use it, like [this](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/notes/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/samples/notes/views/NotesPresenter.java#L85).